# Checking if Mongoose DB is empty

Tags: mongoose

I know I cant query the db with find method and checks if it returns an empty array, but is there any specific method in Mongoose to check if the DB has no objects in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mongo shell you could just do:

```
 if (db.getCollectionNames().length === 0) {
     // It's empty
     ...
 }
```

Each language's driver should have something equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that you are dealing with an asynchronous call, so you should use this:

```
collection.countDocuments(function (err, count) {
    if (!err && count === 0) {
        // It's empty
    }
});
```